# What's another word for "Inspect" that conveys a similar meaning?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to come up with a name for a service where drones will be used to inspect factories and power stations.

**inspect**: *look at something to assess its condition*

I wanted to call it DroneDeploy but that name is already taken by another drone service.

Is there another word for inspect that I could use to convey a suitable meaning?

Comment: We can't help you name things. In order to come up with a similar word to *inspect* you have to tell us what it is about *inspect*, specifically, that you don't like. (And "it being taken" isn't a good English reason.)

Comment: See *inspect* synonyms in online dictionaries and the thesaurus.

Answer (score 1):

Drone... Surveil? ...Watch? ... Guard? ...Thesaurus? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inspect?s=t

Answer (score 0):

When used transitively, "con" can mean "to inspect or examine." "Scan" can also fit the meaning you want. Using a reliable thesaurus and checking the definition of the various synonyms for definitional nuances is probably the best thing to do.